# What is the difference between .send()" and .write() in ruby sockets?

Tags: ruby, sockets

```
require 'socket'

host = 'localhost'
something = 'Ruby'

port = 2000

t = TCPServer.new(host, port)
t.write(something)
t.close


c = TCPServer.new(host, port)
c.send(something)
c.close
```

What are the differences (if any?) between these methods sending data. Are they the same or is one better to use than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's any real difference, it's one of those hangovers from BSD and C++ that you find in a lot of the I/O stdlib.

The difference in BSD/C++ is that `write` is equivalent to `send` with no flags set, but I'm not sure whether there's even any flags to set in the Ruby version.

The method with the most useful difference would be `puts` as per any other IO object, in that it automatically adds a newline.

Comment: I'm sorry for sounding like a noob here, but what do you mean by "flags"

Comment: So, if you had a method call like `say_hello("World", capitalize: true)` then the `capitalize` param would be considered a flag, because it can be either on or off.  In the C++ world that's typically done via actual bits usually in a bitfield, but in either case it means "turn these behaviours on or off".